# Implicit Function Theorem to Prove Smoothness

Tags: calculus, implicit-function-theorem

We are wanting to prove a function is smooth and wondering if the implicit function theorem is useful for such things.

More concretely, suppose that $F\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R\colon (x,y) \mapsto F(x,y)$ is a smooth function. Let $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that
$$F(x,f(x)) = 0$$
and $\partial_y F(x,f(x)) \neq 0$.
Does the implicit function theorem automatically imply that $f$ is smooth?

Comment: Since there is a formula for the derivative of $f$ and the terms involved are smooth the answer is yes.

Comment: I suppose I am worried about an example like: $F(x,y) = (1-x)(1-xy)$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $1/x$ if $x \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q$. We have $F(x,f(x)) \equiv 0$, but clearly $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: You lost me completely. The implicit function theorem shows that under certain circumstances that a differentiable $f$ exists that satisfies the equation. I do not understand the connection between the implicit function $f$ and the discontinuous example you gave?

Comment: Can the IFT indirectly prove a function is smooth? That is, if you know that a function $f$ satisfies $F(x,f(x)) =0$ with $F$ smooth and non-vanishing Jacobian, then does the IFT imply that $f$ is smooth? This note: http://www.tricki.org/article/Use_the_implicit_function_theorem_to_prove_smoothness suggests something to that effect, but I am doubting the claim.

Comment: No. It just says that there is a 'local' differentiable $f$ that solves the system, not that any solution is differentiable. If the $f$ is unique then it says something.

Comment: That makes sense and gels with my understanding of the IFT. So my "counterexample" lacks uniqueness. Thanks!

Comment: It is a very subtle theorem.